# Update Complication via WCSession

Tags: swift, wcsession

I want to update my Complication via an WCSession but noting seems to work. I'm updating my complication every 10 minutes (I saw that this was the max). But nothing happens. Can anyone see the problem in my code.

I have implemented the needed delegates for the update. What is the issue here? Thank you very much!

import ClockKit
    import WatchConnectivity

```
class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource, WCSessionDelegate {

    var session : WCSession!
    var level = 0;

    // MARK: - Timeline Configuration

    func getSupportedTimeTravelDirections(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void) {
        //handler([.forward, .backward])
        handler([])
    }

    func getTimelineStartDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getTimelineEndDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getPrivacyBehavior(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior) -> Void) {
        handler(.showOnLockScreen)
    }

    // MARK: - Timeline Population

    func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the current timeline entry

        switch complication.family {

        case .modularSmall:
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingText()
            template.textProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "\(level)")
            let result = self.level / 100;
            template.fillFraction = Float(result)
            handler(CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: NSDate() as Date, complicationTemplate: template))
        default:
            NSLog("%@", "Unknown complication type: \(complication.family)")
            handler(nil)
        }

        handler(nil)
    }

    func getNextRequestedUpdateDateWithHandler(handler: (NSDate?) -> Void) {
        handler(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 600))
    }

    func requestedUpdateDidBegin() {
        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.default()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }

        if(session.activationState.rawValue == 2){
            checkValue{(isResponse) -> Void in
                self.level = isResponse;
                let server=CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
                for complication in server.activeComplications! {
                    server.reloadTimeline(for: complication)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        if (activationState.rawValue == 2){
            checkValue{(isResponse) -> Void in
                self.level = isResponse;
                let server=CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
                for complication in server.activeComplications! {
                    server.reloadTimeline(for: complication)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    func checkValue(completionHandler : @escaping ((_ response : Int) -> Void))  {
        if WCSession.isSupported() {

            session = WCSession.default()

            session.sendMessage(["getValue": ""], replyHandler: { (dict) -> Void in

                completionHandler(round(dict["value"] as! Double * 100).toInt()!)
            }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                print("InterfaceController session error: \(error)")
                completionHandler(1111) //our error code
            })
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {

    }

    func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, before date: Date, limit: Int, withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the timeline entries prior to the given date
        handler(nil)
    }

    func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, after date: Date, limit: Int, withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the timeline entries after to the given date
        handler(nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Placeholder Templates

    func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
        handler(nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about your problem but since the OS creates the complication controller object for you, I would suggest creating a custom object for the `WCSessionDelegate` methods.

Comment: My Complication isn't updating.

Comment: I meant I don't have a solution, but I suggest you start by creating a new class to handle the `WCSession`.

Comment: As mentioned by @EmilioPelaez, I would put WCSessionDelegate code in separate class. You can also put breakpoint at activationDidCompleteWith method to check if it's getting called or not.